# My Program works fine, but while compiling it warns -Wwritable-strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, warnings

My Program works fine, but while compiling it shows a warning that:
"ISO C11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
        list.get_string("Enter a String: ");"

The code goes like this:

```
char * getString(char *str)
{
    int ch, i;
    char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizeof(char) + 1);
    i=0;
    printf("%s", str);
    while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        ptr[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Why is it showing a warning in my code? 
Also, the code looks a little bit messy. Is there a better way of writing this code?

Comment: Try: `char *getString(const char *str)` instead. You're passing a fixed, read-only [non-writable] string constant to a function whose argument says that it may try to modify it. BTW, your `malloc` only allocates 5 bytes (i.e. `(4 * 1) + 1`). Probably not enough in most cases.

Comment: Tip: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.

Comment: Yup, that works. Now, when I try to check for the memory leaks using valgrind it shows:

==1897== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1897==     in use at exit: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==1897==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 1,029 bytes allocated
==1897==
==1897== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1897==    definitely lost: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==1897==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1897==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1897==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1897==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1897== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory

Comment: If I use free(ptr) it will not return any thing.

Comment: @PuneetChandiok that's another topic, please ask another question.

Comment: @PuneetChandiok BTW: `sizeof(int) * sizeof(char) + 1` is not what you think it is. Show the code that calls `getString` including the declaration of the relevant variables. Then I can tell you more.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * get_string(const char *str)
{
        int ch, i=0;
        char *ptr2;
        char *ptr = malloc( sizeof (char) * sizeof (int) + 1 );
        printf("%s", str);
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
                ptr[i]=ch;
                i++;
        }
        strcpy(ptr2, ptr);
        free(ptr);
        return ptr2;
}

int main()
{
        char *str;
        str = get_string("Enter a String: ");
        printf("%s\n", str);
        return 0;
}

Comment: I'm trying to create a function which returns a string typed by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer with the code you updated in the comment.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char * get_string(const char *str) 
{ 
    int ch, i=0; 
    char *ptr2; 
    char *ptr = malloc( sizeof (char) * sizeof (int) + 1 ); 
    printf("%s", str); 
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') { 
        ptr[i]=ch; 
        i++; 

    } 
    strcpy(ptr2, ptr); 
    free(ptr); 
    return ptr2; 

} 
int main() { 
    char *str; 
    str = get_string("Enter a String: "); 
    printf("%s\n", str); 
    return 0; 

}
```

You do not need to use `ptr2` you can just use `ptr` and return it. But, if you still want to use `ptr2` you have to allocate for it because you use `strcpy` to copy `ptr` to `ptr2`.

```
char *ptr = malloc( sizeof (char) * sizeof (int) + 1 );
```

This line is so weird. It's not wrong, but not so clear for understanding the code. You can define `MAX_LEN` of string, then using `malloc` with it.

For example:

```
#define MAX_LEN 256
char * get_string(const char *str) {
   ...
   char *ptr = malloc(MAX_LEN);
   ...
}
```

It make easier to understand for other people when they read your code.

You should check the return of `malloc`, because it may be failed.

The code i propose (the explications are in the code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 256

char * getString(const char * str) 
{
    printf("%s",str);
    char * str2 = malloc(MAX_LEN); // string length ups to 255
    if(!str2) {return NULL;} // check return of malloc function
    fgets(str2, MAX_LEN, stdin); // using fgets to get string from keyboard (from redirect file is another story)
    str2[strcspn ( str2, "\n" )] = '\0'; // remove '\n' character
    return str2; 

} 
int main() { 
    char *str = getString("Enter a String: "); 
    if(!str) {
       printf("%s\n", str); 
       free(str); // free str (str2 that you allocated in getString function) to avoid memory leaks.
    }
    return 0; 

}
```